# Use a local variable in a request

Tags: python, variables, refresh, global, local

I try to import proxies in my code.

I tried t oselect a random proxy in my request but I didn't get there

This is my code (python)

```
import random
import requests

#create global variable to use in proxy_slct
rdmproxy = "1.1.1.1:1"

#get proxies from file + randomize and select
def proxy_slct():
    global rdmproxy
    threading.Timer(5.0, proxytimer).start()
    proxy_file = open('proxies.txt').read().splitlines()
    rdmproxy = random.choice(proxy_file)
    f.close()
proxytimer()

#request
try:
    login = requests.get("https://httpbin.org/ip", proxies=rdmproxy, timeout=5)
    print(login.json())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you define `rmdproxy` at the top of your code and then overwrite it?

Try with this:

```
import random
import requests

def proxy_slct():
    global rdmproxy
    threading.Timer(5.0, proxytimer).start()
    with open('proxies.txt') as file:
        proxy_file = file.read().splitlines()
        rdmproxy = random.choice(proxy_file)
proxytimer()

try:
    login = requests.get("https://httpbin.org/ip", proxies=rdmproxy, timeout=5)
    print(login.json())
```

As you can see you didin't initialize `rmdproxy` on the global scope but in the local scope with the keyword global, the you assign a random value to that variable.

Also try to print that variable so you could see if its value is what you want it to be.